# Mongodb Query Less than specified time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

document as below

```
chatid:121212,
 messages:[
      {
      msg:'Hello',
      time:'2021-04-17T16:35:25.879Z'
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I want query all record where time less than specified timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kr51g6hb9Qz

Use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter the records

[$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$messages" }, //  break into individual documents
  { $match: { "messages.time": { $lt: "2021-04-17T16:39:24.879Z" } } }
])
```

Comment: Why this is not working for $lt: new Date() ?

Comment: `"messages.time"` is date or string type check in DB

Comment: It's showing as string. But I always put time by new Date() in it